# Using OnMounted and Axios Requests in Pinia

Tags: vue.js, axios, state-management, pinia

I am creating a website that offers some products and also has individual product pages. I am just struggling at understanding the order in which data should be loaded. I could obviously make the axios call and pass this data as a prop to the next component but I plan to reuse this data on other pages and components so I wanted to store the product info in a store:

```
//using composition api in Pinia
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useProductStore = defineStore('layout', () => {
  const products = ref([]);

  products.value = getProducts();

  const getProducts = () => {
    axios
      .get(window.location.origin + '/assets/data.json')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data.error);
        return null;
      });
  };

  const getProductData = (id) => {
    var productData = products.value.filter((obj) => {
      return obj['ID'] === id;
    });

    return productData;
  };

  onMounted(() => {
    getProducts();
  });

  return { products, getProductData };
});
```

I need to load the data when the site starts since this data will be used by various components such as the product page or my shop page section listing all the products. Is it incorrect to load it on mount inside pinia as I do above? Also here is how I am trying to use this data which does draw an error:

```
<template>
  <div class="skew-cc"></div>
  <div class="white-block"></div>
  <div
    class="service-block q-pa-lg text-center column no-wrap flex-center block-wrapper"
    id="Products"
  >
    <h2 class="text-h2 text-weight-bolder text-dark q-mb-xs">
      Freestanding Stoves & Inserts
    </h2>
    <h6
      class="text-h6 text-weight-light text-dark q-mt-none"
      style="max-width: 800px"
    >
      Take a look at some of gas, wood, and pellet stoves below or come visit
      our showroom in Bel Air, MD and check them out in person!
    </h6>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <div
      class="service-block column no-wrap flex-center block-wrapper"
      style="margin-bottom: 100px"
    >
      <q-btn
        aria-label="filter"
        align="around"
        class="btn-fixed-width self-end q-ma-lg"
        color="primary"
        label="Filter"
        rounded
        outline
        icon="fa-solid fa-filter"
        @click="productFiltersDrawer = !productFiltersDrawer"
      />
      <q-drawer
        v-model="productFiltersDrawer"
        bordered
        side="right"
        behavior="mobile"
        :width="$q.screen.width >= 600 ? 600 : $q.screen.width"
      >
        <q-scroll-area class="fit q-pa-md">
          <q-btn
            flat
            round
            icon="fa-solid fa-xmark"
            aria-label="Menu"
            @click="productFiltersDrawer = !productFiltersDrawer"
            style="margin: 20px"
          />
          <div class="text-center filter-form">
            <h4 class="text-weight-bolder q-my-xs row justify-center">
              <q-icon
                name="fa-solid fa-filter"
                color="Black"
                size="sm"
                class="self-center q-ma-sm"
              />
              PRODUCT FILTERS
            </h4>
            <div class="text-subtitle1 text-accent q-mb-xl">
              Please use the following filters to find your perfect stove!
            </div>
            <q-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset">
              <div class="row q-col-gutter-md text-left">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <q-select
                    filled
                    v-model="typeOfService"
                    :options="options"
                    label="Fuel Source"
                    hide-bottom-space
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <q-select
                    filled
                    v-model="typeOfService"
                    :options="options"
                    label="Unit Type"
                    hide-bottom-space
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <q-select
                    filled
                    v-model="typeOfService"
                    :options="options"
                    label="Unit Size"
                    hide-bottom-space
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div
                    class="text-subtitle1 text-accent q-mb-lg"
                    style="padding-left: 10px"
                  >
                    Efficiency (%)
                  </div>
                  <q-range
                    v-model="label"
                    :min="0"
                    :max="100"
                    :step="1"
                    label-always
                    color="primary"
                    class="q-px-md q-py-sm"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <q-btn
                    :loading="loading"
                    color="primary"
                    label="Apply"
                    class="full-width q-pa-md"
                    unelevated
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    <template v-slot:loading>
                      <q-spinner-gears class="q-ma-sm" /> Sending...
                    </template>
                  </q-btn>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <!-- <vue-turnstile ref="reCaptchaTurnstile" site-key="0x4AAAAAAAIGxTIQ6Z8JWGTo" v-model="token" /> -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </q-form>
          </div>
        </q-scroll-area>
      </q-drawer>
      <q-carousel
        v-model="slide"
        transition-prev="slide-right"
        transition-next="slide-left"
        animated
        control-color="primary"
        class="full-height full-width"
      >
        <template v-for="(n, index) in numberOfSlides" :key="index">
          <q-carousel-slide
            :name="n.toString()"
            class="column no-wrap flex-center"
          >
            <div class="row full-width">
              <div
                v-for="(i, index2) in productsPerPage"
                :key="index2"
                class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 q-pa-sm product-item"
                width="100%"
              >
                <router-link
                  :to="{
                    name: 'Product',
                    props: {
                      id: [index2 + index * productsPerPage]['ID'],
                    },
                  }"
                >
                  <q-img
                    :src="
                      '../assets/Regency Product Photos/' +
                      products[index2 + index * productsPerPage]['Picture Name']
                    "
                    :ratio="4 / 3"
                  />
                </router-link>
                <div class="description text-left text-weight-bold row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <h6
                      class="text-h6 q-mt-sm q-mb-none text-left"
                      style="line-height: 1.25rem; letter-spacing: 0.08em"
                    >
                      {{ products[index2 + index * productsPerPage]['Model'] }}
                    </h6>
                    <div class="text-subtitle1 text-accent">
                      {{
                        products[index2 + index * productsPerPage][
                          'Fuel Source'
                        ]
                      }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="col text-right text-subtitle text-h6 text-weight-regular"
                  >
                    $3.50
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </q-carousel-slide>
        </template>
      </q-carousel>
      <div class="q-pa-lg q-mt-xl flex flex-center">
        <q-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :max="numberOfSlides"
          :max-pages="6"
          :boundary-numbers="false"
          direction-links
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useProductStore } from '../stores/product-store';

const productStore = useProductStore();
const { products } = storeToRefs(productStore);

const productsPerPage = ref(6);
const numberOfSlides = ref(0);
const currentPage = ref(1);
const slide = ref('1');
const typeOfService = ref(null);
const productFiltersDrawer = ref(false);
const loading = ref(false);
const label = ref({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
});

// Drop down value for the services
const options = ['Item 1', 'Item 2'];

//methods
const onReset = () => {
  //reset data
};

const onSubmit = () => {
  //submit data
};

watch(currentPage, (currentValue) => {
  slide.value = currentValue.toString();
});

onMounted(() => {
  numberOfSlides.value = Math.floor(
    products.value.length / productsPerPage.value
  );
});
</script>
```

I draw an error at products.value.length as it says value is undefined. So this makes me think the data isnt loaded correctly in pinia? How should I get the products array in pinia loaded without OnMount() so it can be used in various components?

Comment: It's a mistake to use onMounted in a store. It's component lifecycle hook. Do a request in top-level component and prevent the comps that depend on store data to be rendered before it's available, e.g. with v-if

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your `getProducts()` does not return anything (`undefined`), which is why you are getting the error. You could return the Promise from the axios call, but `products` would be a Promise then, not the actual product list:

```
  products.value = getProducts();
```

Calling `getProducts()` a second time in the `onMounted` loads the data again, but the returned value (`undefined`) is not assigned to anything. I don't think the `onMounted` does much for you anyway, since the store initialization will run just once, and you can run it when the store gets accessed the first time.

---

There are multiple ways to fix it, my suggestion is to have `getProducts()` assign the `products.value` directly. Also, I would add a value to the store, indicating if data is loading (can be a boolean or the promise itself, depending on how you want to use it):

```
export const useProductStore = defineStore('product', () => {
  const products = ref([]);
  const isLoading = ref(false)

  const getProducts = () => {
    isLoading.value = true
    return axios
      .get(window.location.origin + '/assets/data.json')
      .then((response) => {
        products.value = response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data.error);
        products.value = []
      })
      .finally(() => {
         isLoading.value = false
      });
  };

  getProducts();

  return { products, isLoading, getProducts };
});
```

Now components using the store have access to the same products data, and they can check if products are loading and trigger a reload if necessary.

Here is a snippet that demonstrates the behavior (hopefully):

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createPinia, defineStore, mapState } = Pinia;

const useProductStore = defineStore('product', () => {
  const products = ref([]);
  const isLoading = ref(false);

  const loadProducts = async () => {
    isLoading.value = true
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    products.value = [1,2,3]
    isLoading.value = false
  };

  loadProducts()
  
  return { products, isLoading, loadProducts };
});

const ProducDisplayComponent = {
  template: `
    <div v-if="isLoading">loading...</div>
    <div v-else>{{products}}</div>
  `,
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useProductStore, ['products', 'isLoading' ])
  }
}

const LoadProductsButtonComponent = {
  template: `<button @click="loadProducts">Reload products</button>`,
  setup(){
    const {loadProducts} = useProductStore()
    return {
      loadProducts
    }
  }
}

const App = {
  components: {ProducDisplayComponent, LoadProductsButtonComponent},
  template: `
    <button @click="displays++">Add product display</button>
    <LoadProductsButtonComponent v-if="displays > 0"/>
    <ProducDisplayComponent v-for="i in displays" :key="i"/>
  `,
  setup(){
    return {
      displays: ref(0)
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>
```

Comment: The only issue with this approach is what if someone goes to the individual product page first via url so I would be running getProduct() in there also to fill the array despite I really only need to run a seperate function which gets the indivdual data in that products array.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean the `getProductData()` function? Wouldn't it work exactly as in your question?

Comment: Yea forget my last comment it was a bit confusing. I also added a getProduct() function to get an individual product from the products array. Its working however, I am curious you used async for your loadProducts function. However, in the code above that you edited of mine you did not use async or await for the axios call. Should I add that to it so the code cannot complete without the axios request being done?

Comment: Oh, when an await occurs, the function terminates and returns a Promise, the rest of the function is put into a `then()` on the Promise. So semantically, both function are the same. You could write `await getProducts()`, even though that function is not async. But I think Pinia cannot handle an async setup function, so it is not possible to await the load call inside the setup. One way or another, the Vue components have to detect and react to the loading state or start with the empty array and then updated. Do you know what I mean, does that make sense?